# vue.js element ui bind boolean data to selection column

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element

How to bind a boolean data to the checkboxes in the selection column to show user whether the row is selected or not.

Here is JSFiddle Link:

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/5jqhxn0g/)

Table:

```
 <el-table ref="multipleTable" :data="tableData3" style="width: 100%" @selection-change="handleSelectionChange">
<el-table-column type="selection" width="55"  property="key">
</el-table-column>
<el-table-column label="Date" width="120">
  <template slot-scope="scope">{{ scope.row.date }}</template>
</el-table-column>
<el-table-column property="name" label="Name" width="120">
</el-table-column>
<el-table-column property="address" label="Address" show-overflow-tooltip>
</el-table-column>
```

```
tableData3: [{
          date: '2016-05-03',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
          key:true
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-02',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
          key:true
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
          key:false
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-01',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',          
          key:true
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-08',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
          key:true
        }],
```

needed to bind key values to the first column of the table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, you have a `key` property in each of the rows of your `tableData3` data. You want to show the user whether the row has been selected or not depending on if `key` is `true` or `false`.

You could do that in the `mounted` method:

1. You select the rows to toggle by removing the ones that are false using the array's `filter` method.
2. You toggle these rows using the `toggleSelection` method

```js
mounted() {
  const rowsToToggle = this.tableData3.filter(row => row.key)
  this.toggleSelection(rowsToToggle)
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jqhxn0g/3/) with the associated behavior. Hope it help you.

Comment: For data representation it is ok. What about the user inputs, when user select or deselect rows, how can the "key" values be updated?